# FieldValue.increment for Cloud Firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a android app using flutter and Firebase Firestore.
I would like to add that new FieldValue.increment functionality which is apperently available in Firebase since this april but i've got an error: 
    `The method 'increment' isn't defined for the class 'FieldValue'.`

Here is my code that i've tried:

```
onTap: (){
  Firestore.instance.document('docRef').updateData({"numberOfDocs": FieldValue.increment(1)});
}
```

I'm just a beginner programmer but when i checked that field_value.dart file it's missing "increment" implementation.
So, is it right answer to say that flutter team didn't yet implemented that functionality?

I've seen a tutorial where increment is already used in some .js code but for me it's not working.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ejn1FLRRaw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can see in the [change log for FlutterFire](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-changelog-tab-), the increment operator has not been added yet.

I added a [feature request to the repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31034).

Comment: Thanks Peter. I was just browsing the [CloudFirestore plugin code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java#L706-L713) myself, with the same findings. I'll add an issue/FR for it.

Comment: This seems to be in the master repo now: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1491

Answer (score 23):

This has been added to the [`cloud_firestore` Flutter plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore) as of [version `0.10.0`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore/versions/0.10.0#-changelog-tab-).

You can use *`FieldValue.increment`* with a `double` (e.g. `FieldValue.increment(1.0)`) or an `int` (e.g. `FieldValue.increment(2)`).

---

[Here is the relevant pull request](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1491).

<sup><strike>If anyone reads this before the version is pushed to Pub: The link to the version will not yet work, but in the meantime you can use [this Git commit](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1543), which contains a fix I did.</strike></sup>

Answer (score 17):

User that Import:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

For Increment:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('post').doc(postId).update({"like": FieldValue.increment(1)});
```

For Decrement:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('post').doc(postId).update({"like": FieldValue.increment(-1)});
```