# increment a value in firestore with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

hi i am trying to increment a value when clicked the button if data is available in firestore this is my code bloc if you have any suggestion lmk please

```
 int q = 0;

    final snapShot = await Firestore.instance.collection('cart').document("LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd").get();
    if(snapShot.exists){
      q=q+1;


    }
    Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
      await transaction.update(
          Firestore.instance
              .collection("cart")
              .document("LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd"),
          {
            foodItem.name: {
              'itemName': foodItem.name,
              'imgUrl': foodItem.imageAssetPath,
              'itemPrice': foodItem.price,
              'quantity': q,
            }
          });

    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In November 2021, this worked for me.

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(currentUser?.id).update({
      'bronzeBadges': FieldValue.increment(2),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var quantityref = db.collection("cart").document("LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd");
```

// Increment the quantity field by 1.

```
quantityref.update({
"quantity" : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)});
```

Comment: Sir this code is not working for flutter.

Answer (score 0):

If your want to change a value based on the previous one, you have basically two approaches:

1. Make use of transactions. I see you're doing that but incorrectly, because you're fetching the current value outside of it, and it could change by the moment you run the update, causing data inconsistencies. I don't know about Flutter, but as far as I know, a Transaction in Firebase consists in a read operation followed by one or more write operations, and the value returned from the read will be the very last one and won't be changed before you finish the transaction, so you can be sure you're working with the latest one. I suggest you to read the Transactions docs.
2. `increment` method **(recommended)**: See this [see this answer for incrementing in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55868600/5819227)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to get the desired document and its elements to update the document of fields. In your example, it is quantity.

First, get the document:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('cart')
    .document('documentID')
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
  // use ds, parse ds then access the quantity
});
```

After doing the job, you need to update the field. Thankfully, there is an updateData function in firestore instance.

```
    db.collection('cart')
    .document('documentID')
    .updateData({'quantity': someQuantity});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: dostum calismadi malesef

Comment: i tried this code but it did not work          Firestore db = Firestore.instance;
        final snapShot = await Firestore.instance
            .collection('cart')
            .document("LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd")
            .get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
        if(ds.exists) {
          db.collection('cart')
              .document('LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd')
              .updateData({foodItem.name: {{'quantity': q++}}});
        }

        });

Comment: First of all, you need to learn some concrete basics about Firebase Firestore, I strongly suggest you to learn that one before diving into a project but still I want to answer your question. After obtaining DocumentSnapshot ds, all you have to do is using foreach to iterate its elements. You can use it like: ds.forEach((k,v){ if ( k == "quantity" ) { int variable = int.parse(v) } }) As you see, you got the value you want. Now you need to bring the variable out of the local scope then store it in order to use it on increment as you mentioned. Finally, you can update your quantity in a right way

Comment: @MehmetReşatDemir You do not have to write something about foodItem.name namely other fields unless you want to change it.

Comment: An operation based on a previous value should be made by using Transaction (incorrectly used by OP) or the `increment` method. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55868600/5819227